# URL Rewrite for Internal (SEO) that Eliminates Original Link

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, seo

My site is built in php and I have URL rewrites to make the .php links more SEO friendly:

```
RewriteRule ^page-one$ /pageone.php [L]
```

The problem with this is that someone, including Google bots, can still see pageone.php from when it was previously indexed. So I end up with two links for each page. That's bad.

How can I set this up so that I get the benefit of rewriting to page-one, while somehow making sure an external request to pageone.php is redirected to page-one?

Answer (score 0):

How about redirecting page-one.php to pageone?

```
RewriteRule ^page-one.php$ /pageone [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: What happens when you try to access page-one directly though, which is how the internal links are set up?

Comment: With both rules in place it should work. page-one.php gets redirected to page-one. page-one gets rewritten to page-one.php on the server.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. I tried this and get page not found on the about-us

RewriteRule ^aboutus.php$ /about-us [R,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^about-us$ /aboutus.php [L]